# how can i Add an editable input text with (react js )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

any one who can help please

I am using React JS and I have a text field which is supposed to change its content as the user clicks on it. I also want to be able to edit the text in that text field

please i searched about it too much but couldn't find a solution any one will help i will be thankfull for her || him

this is AddNewMaintinanceDown component the main constructure for the component

the text input here it is another component i declared it in another place (you can replace it with  input tag and type text)

```
import React, {Fragment ,useState } from 'react'
import TextInput from '../../../components/Inputs/TextInput/TextInput'
import {CgAddR} from  'react-icons/cg'



const AddNewMaintinanceDown = (props) => {

    const [isThereAnyText,setIsThereAnyText]=useState()
    
    const [enteredMaintinance, setEnteredMaintinance] = useState()
   
    const maintinanceTextHandeler=(event) => {
        

        if(event.target.value.trim().length > 0 ){
            
            setIsThereAnyText(false)   
        
          } 
          
          if(event.target.value.trim().length <= 0 ) {
            setIsThereAnyText(true)  
          }

        setEnteredMaintinance(event.target.value)
        
    }


    const addNewMaintinance = (event) => {
        

        if (enteredMaintinance.trim().length > 0) {
            setIsThereAnyText(false) 
        }
        
        if (enteredMaintinance.trim().length <= 0) {
            setIsThereAnyText(true) 
        }
        
        props.onAddMaintinanceHandeler(enteredMaintinance)
        
        setEnteredMaintinance("")
        setIsThereAnyText(true) 
    }
    
    
    
    return (
        <Fragment>

        <span class="flex items-center">
        <TextInput
        onChange={maintinanceTextHandeler}
        placeholder="the user will put the data here"
        colliderClassName="w-full"
        className="w-full "
        value={enteredMaintinance}
        
        >
        </TextInput>
        
        <Fragment
        className="flex justify-center w-8 min-w-11 min-h-11 h-11 bg-dark-10 text-primary1"
        style={{ borderRadius: "100%", height: 50, width: 50 }}
        >

        <span className=" text-primary1">
        <button type='button' onClick={addNewMaintinance} disabled={isThereAnyText} ><CgAddR style={{marginTop:"3PX"}}size={"3em"}  /> </button>
        
        </span>
        </Fragment>
        </span>        
        </Fragment>
                
    )
}

export default AddNewMaintinanceDown
```

and this is MaintinanceList component the things that user write it will come as a text and the user will be able to edit it (this the problem that i have i coudnt to make it)

```
import React, {Fragment , useState , Component} from 'react'

import { FiTrash } from 'react-icons/fi'
import TextInput from "../../../components/Inputs/TextInput/TextInput";

const MaintinanceList = (props) => {
    const deleteHandeler=(event , index) => {
    
        props.onsetAddMaintinance( (prevdata) => {
        return prevdata.filter((element ,elIndex) => (elIndex !== index) )})
    }
    
    return (
        <Fragment>
        <ul >
        {props.MaintinanceFirstValue.map((maintinanceprops , index) => (
            <div style={{display:"flex",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"space-between",alignContent:"center",marginTop:"2%",padding:"10px",borderRadius:"12px", border:"1px solid #757575"}} >
            <span style={{display:"flex", alignItems:"center"}}>
            <p>{index+1}-)</p>
            <li    style={{marginLeft:"10px"}} >
            
            <TextInput 
            key={Math.random()}
            value={maintinanceprops.maintinanceText}
          
            ></TextInput> 
            
            
            </li>
            
            </span>

            <FiTrash  onClick={(e) => {deleteHandeler(e ,index)}}    style={{marginRight:"7px"}}></FiTrash>

            </div>
        ))}
        
        </ul>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default MaintinanceList
```

and i import this tow component like this

```
<div className="w-full mt-4 border-default border-dark40 rounded-12 p-4">
            <AddNewMaintinanceDown onAddMaintinanceHandeler={AddMaintinanceHandeler}/>
            <MaintinanceList MaintinanceFirstValue={addMaintinance} onsetAddMaintinance={setAddMaintinance}></MaintinanceList>
            </div>
```

and before this i wrote these in the main component that i imported the tow component there

```
const [addMaintinance , setAddMaintinance]=useState([]);
  
  const AddMaintinanceHandeler = (maintinanceText) => {
    
    setAddMaintinance ((prevİnformation) => {
      return [...prevİnformation ,{maintinanceText}]
    })
  }
```

and the last state the page will be like this but i coudnt to make the inputs editable here

[the last state for the page will be like this ][1]

please guys help me with this how can i make the text in the list editable

i will be so happy for any help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejtht.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify what *"change its content as the user clicks on it"* means? Change it how and from what source? Also where exactly are you stuck implementing this feature? What part of it currently  works and what doesn't?

Comment: I meant the test1 , test2 and test3 the content of the input the user will be able to edit it like this (test125846) and the input will take the value and update it you can look to the picture that i added